# Unable to understand watchkit extension crash

Tags: swift, xcode, watchkit, watchos

I am getting these crash reports on Xcode organizer from users of the app. It does not show any line of my code in the crash, looks like it crashed on init. I do not know how to progress with the debug. Can you please help:

```
Thread 0#0  (null) in 0x300000 ()
#1  (null) in 0x300000 ()
#2  (null) in _WKInterfaceControllerCreateClass ()
#3  (null) in __115-[SPRemoteInterface createViewController:className:properties:contextID:info:gestureDescriptions:clientIdentifier:]_block_invoke_3 ()
#4  (null) in __115-[SPRemoteInterface createViewController:className:properties:contextID:info:gestureDescriptions:clientIdentifier:]_block_invoke_2 ()
#5  (null) in spUtils_dispatchAsyncToMainThread ()
#6  (null) in __115-[SPRemoteInterface createViewController:className:properties:contextID:info:gestureDescriptions:clientIdentifier:]_block_invoke ()
#7  (null) in -[SPRemoteInterface performAfterApplicationDidFinishLaunching:] ()
#8  (null) in -[SPRemoteInterface createViewController:className:properties:contextID:info:gestureDescriptions:clientIdentifier:] ()
#9  (null) in __140-[SPExtensionConnection interfaceViewController:createCompanionControllerClass:properties:initializationContextID:info:gestureDescriptions:]_block_invoke ()
#10 (null) in __62-[SPExtensionConnection performOnSendQueue:syncIfUnsuspended:]_block_invoke.583 ()
#11 (null) in spUtils_dispatchAsyncToMainThread ()
#12 (null) in -[SPExtensionConnection performOnSendQueue:syncIfUnsuspended:] ()
#13 (null) in -[SPExtensionConnection interfaceViewController:createCompanionControllerClass:properties:initializationContextID:info:gestureDescriptions:] ()
#14 (null) in -[SPApplicationDelegate interfaceViewController:createCompanionControllerClass:properties:initializationContextID:] ()
#15 (null) in -[SPInterfaceViewController loadView] ()
#16 (null) in -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] ()
#17 (null) in -[UIViewController view] ()
#18 (null) in -[SPModalViewController setContentViewController:] ()
#19 (null) in -[SPApplicationDelegate extensionConnection:interfaceViewController:presentViewController:info:initializationContextID:] ()
#20 (null) in -[SPExtensionConnection handlePlistDictionary:] ()
#21 (null) in -[SPExtensionConnection handleProtoPlist:] ()
#22 (null) in __43-[SPExtensionConnection receiveData:reply:]_block_invoke ()
#23 (null) in spUtils_dispatchAsyncToMainThread ()
#24 (null) in -[SPExtensionConnection receiveData:reply:] ()
#25 (null) in -[SPRemoteInterface performForClientConnections:directToUIBlock:] ()
#26 (null) in __54-[SPRemoteInterface sendData:clientIdentifiers:reply:]_block_invoke ()
#27 (null) in spUtils_dispatchAsyncToMainThread ()
#28 (null) in -[SPRemoteInterface sendData:clientIdentifiers:reply:] ()
#29 (null) in -[SPRemoteInterface sendData:clientIdentifiers:] ()
#30 (null) in -[SPRemoteInterface sendPlist:clientIdentifiers:] ()
#31 (null) in -[SPRemoteInterface controller:presentInterfaceController:initializationContextID:] ()
#32 (null) in +[SPRemoteInterface controller:presentInterfaceController:context:] ()
#33 (null) in __59-[WKInterfaceController presentControllerWithName:context:]_block_invoke ()
#34 (null) in -[WKInterfaceController presentControllerWithName:context:] ()
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. In my case, the issue was that I changed the watch app extension name, so it doesn't include the underscore character. After this, I experienced this crash.

The solution was, to go into the storyboard file of the watch app extension, and in the identity inspector of the existing view controllers, I just retyped the name of the custom class names, and the module updated automatically. After this, it worked. Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: retyping probably causes the reassignment of the target - that is probably what fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI. The issue that I had was one of those embarrassing ones.

The storyboard had "Inherit Module From Target" on.

However, the default layout that Apple creates, has the executable in a separate (Extension) target.

I need to uncheck that box, and explicitly reference my extension target.

D'oh!